# Why does an event loop have one or more task queues?

Tags: javascript, browser, event-loop

[An event loop has one or more task queues.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-queue).

According to what is said later in this specification:

> Tasks encapsulate algorithms that are responsible for such work as:
>
> Events: ...
>
> Parsing: ...
>
> Callbacks: ...
>
> Using a resource: ...
>
> Reacting to DOM manipulation: ...

> Formally, a task is a struct which has:
>
> Steps: ...
>
> A source: ....

Can I think that every event loop has one or more taskqueues, then author has many operations(`Events, Callbacks...`), these operations will be put into corresponding task queue.

Like following picture.

[image]

> Per its source field, each task is defined as coming from a specific task source. For each event loop, **every task source must be associated with a specific task queue.**

> For example, a user agent could **have one task queue for mouse and key events** (to which the user interaction task source is associated), and **another to which all other task sources are associated.** Then, using the freedom granted in the initial step of the event loop processing model, it could give keyboard and mouse events preference over other tasks three-quarters of the time, keeping the interface responsive but not starving other task queues. Note that in this setup, the processing model still enforces that the user agent would never process events from any one task source out of order.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if my understanding is correct. : )

Comment: @MisterJojo Thank you for pointing that out., `because the event loop processing model grabs the first runnable task from the chosen queue, instead of dequeuing the first task.`. What I am thinking about is whether my task structure is correct.

Comment: @MisterJojo Maybe my expression is not clear.. Every browser page has an event loop.

Comment: @MisterJojo I'm curious about whether the task queue of Event loop will have the above structure. `One of the task sources, used to group and serialize related tasks.`

Comment: ok; Every browser page has an event loop, but  every page can't comunicate with the other, so, whch interest ?

Comment: @MisterJojo It's not these problems.. I just want to know which queues the task source is put into. e.g. ajax operation will be put into ajax task queue.

Comment: in any browser there is only one page active at a time, the others are freezed. there is also sanboxing. in any page ther is only one event  loop, but an unique event can be proceeds on multiple [sub] elments and that make a set, not a new queue. they are done one by one, and there is no thread. Ajax process are separate and doen't concern event loop

Comment: @MisterJojo ..., My bad, I mean ajax's callbacks will be put in **set**.

Comment: @MisterJojo Use the example of timer(setTimeout), will it be put into corresponding timer set?

Comment: @OnlyWick I read the comments you guys discussed. I think you maybe has a misunderstanding the queues means.An event loop, like the name, is a loop which means it execute as long as the queue is not empty. But The event loop always will finish all tasks in CURRENT queue, then it turns to  execute the microTasks. And after the microTasks are finished, it goes back to Task Queue. But This task queue is not same with the last one, it's a new queue which can be made by many ways, such as execute setTimeout/setInterval/ in your last queue, or your ajax is answerred by server and so on ...

Comment: @MisterJojo Another question, `instead of dequeuing the first task.`. Don't you need to remove the task in the set after execution?

Comment: @Tony_zha I know these, I'm curious about the structure of this queue.

Comment: what ever; this is a stack

Comment: @Tony_zha 留个 V.

Comment: @OnlyWick Vnum: tongningsky

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900239/is-there-really-a-prioritization-system-for-the-task-queues, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627773/which-types-of-queues-are-in-event-loop

Comment: @Bergi The tutorials found in our country only show one task queue and one micro task queue, but we don't see that there are multiple task queues.

Comment: @OnlyWick Well every tutorial should start simple… what were you reading?

Comment: @Bergi The articles I read a long time ago are wrong, and now these wrong things have been abandoned by me.

Comment: If you already know that, then what is your actual question? I'm having trouble to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the two links. HTML standards only describes some behaviors roughly, but doesn't go deep into concrete implementation. It's really difficult to understand these. I think I just need to understand what's in the specification.

Comment: @Bergi Actual question is browser's implemention other than concept of Event loop.

Comment: If you want to ask about a particular browser implementation you should probably adjust the question title

Answer (score 1):

A [*task*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task), as defined by the HTML specs is a specs construct. It allows to execute algorithms asynchronously. These algorithm might involve calling some JS script, but that's not a given. Also, all JS isn't executed from a *task*, for instance all the callbacks in the [update the rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) aren't called from a task. So seeing a 1-to-1 relationship between *tasks*  and the JS runtime is often misleading. And this graph you shown seems completely wrong. UI event are sent by the OS to one of the browser's processes, which [will communicate to the event-loop's process through IPC](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication/) and queue the various tasks there. The event-loop will then pick one such task and yet again delegate to various other processes and sometime wait for these to do their job, like it does for the process where the JS runtime is ran.

As per your quote, the HTML specs do not require that there are multiple event-queues. What they do require however, is that there are multiple [*task-sources*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#task-source). This is to ensure that two tasks, queued on the same *task-source* will execute in the queued order.

During the [event-loop processing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:event-loop), the browser will start by choosing one *task-source* from which it will execute the oldest available task.
This is critical since this allows to have a prioritization system among all the *task-sources*. This is what your quote is talking about when they say that there could be one event-queue for UI events, and one for all the rest, because it is generally preferable to treat UI events as being "user-visible", since they triggered the event they expect a fast visible response to it. Whereas, e.g. for network tasks, a lot of other actors were involved, having a small delay is generally more acceptable.

And indeed, most implementations actually have at least one event-queue dedicated for just the *UI task-source*. But they generally don't have a single task-queue for all the other task-sources. This would mean that a network task queued before a message task would be executed before. Most browsers will have yet another task-queue just for network tasks, and another for timer tasks, and some could even have one per `MessagePort` instance, since [each `MessagePort` has its own *task-source*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#port-message-queue). [Firefox even has one event-queue for timers that are scheduled during the page load](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1270059), and another queue for the ones scheduled afterwards, so that the former can have a lower priority (and match the old Chrome's behavior with their 1ms minimal timeout).

In the near future I even expect this wording about the possibility to have a single event-queue to be removed, because we'll soon have access to the [Prioritized Task Scheduling API](https://wicg.github.io/scheduling-apis/) (it already there in Chrome), which does require multiple task-queues since the priority is enforced there.

So, to recap, yes, you can see the various event-queues as being ordered lists of task to be executed, and yes different *kinds* of task may be queued in different queues. But unless you're using the Prioritized Task Scheduling API, you shouldn't expect any particular behavior as this is currently all let to implementors to decide which behavior they deem the best to their users.

Answer (score -2):

The idea of a **queue** is just conceptual to allow humans to describe the architecture in a way familiar to ordinary people. In code, there is no actual "queue". Because the tasks don't actually queue, they're listed.

In code what you actually have is a task group or set or collection (implemented as an array of tasks or a linked list of tasks.. basically a database of tasks). What actually do the queuing are the events.

The basic program flow is actually fairly simple to understand. The pseudocode looks something like this:

```
while(still_waiting_for(events)) {

  execute_script()

  current_event = wait_for(events)
  current_task = search_related_task(tasks, current_event)
  call_function(current_task.callback)

}
```

In the code above, there's no variable or data structure that represents the event queue. Instead we just have a variable that stores the list of all events we're listening to/waiting for. The actual event "queue" is normally managed by the OS and is invisible in our code.

The `tasks` variable is all the tasks that are waiting for their respective events. Like I previously mention above, this is normally a set or collection of tasks. We call this the task queue but as you can see the tasks are not queuing (lining up) for the events. Instead when an event happens we search the for the corresponding task in `tasks`.

Now, the data structure for different types of tasks may be slightly different (for example, timer tasks are usually handled very differently). So because C/C++ is a typed language one valid way to handle this fact is to have multiple task lists (task queues). Another reason might be that you may want certain type of tasks to be evaluated **before** waiting for any event. The obvious one being callbacks to `setImmediate()`. In which case you have a separate task queue for `setImmediate` callbacks to be processed before everything else:

```
while(still_waiting_for(events)) {

  execute_script()

  for (i=0; i<immediate_tasks.length; i++) {
    immediate = immediate_tasks[i];
    call_function(immediate.callback)
  }

  current_event = wait_for(events)
  current_task = search_related_task(tasks, current_event)
  call_function(current_task.callback)

}
```

The actual coding to implement this in C/C++ may be a bit confusing to a typical C programmer but should be fairly easy to understand for someone used to thinking asynchronously in javascript. The low level function for handling asynchronous events vary depending on what OS you're using (eg, poll/epoll on Linux, overlapped I/O on Windows, kqueue for BSD/Mac OS) and different javascript interpreters handle them in different ways (eg, libuv in Node.js which itself uses epoll or kqueue or overlapped I/O depending on which OS you compile Node.js on) but the basic way they work are similar.

I'm going to use the cross-platform (POSIX) [select()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) function to demonstrate how the `wait_for(events)` part actually work in real code:

```
while(1) {
  retval = select(maxNumberOfIO, readableIOList, writableIOList, NULL, timeout);

  if (retval == -1) {
    perror("Invalid select()");
  }
  else if (retval) {
    //  Find which file descriptor triggered the event
    for (i=0; i<maxNumberOfIO; i++) {
      if (FD_ISSET(i, readableIOList) && readable_task_queue[i]) {
        call_js_callback(readable_task_queue[i]);
      }
      if (FD_ISSET(i, writableIOList) && writable_task_queue[i]) {
        call_js_callback(writable_task_queue[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the `select()` system call, if you pass in `0` as the value of `timeout` it will wait forever for an event to happen. This allows you to set a time limit for waiting in case you need to execute other code (eg. waiting for keyboard or mouse event which may not use the `select()` system call to communicate with your process). This timeout also allows us a simple way to implement timer events like `setTimeout` and `setInterval`:

```
while(1) {
  // Calculate value of timeout:
  nearest_timer = find_nearest_timer(timer_task_queue);
  
  gettimeofday(&current_time, NULL);

  now_millisecs = current_time.tv_sec*1000 + current_time.tv_usec/1000;

  next_timeout_millisecs = nearest_timer.timeout - now_millisecs;
  if (next_timeout_millisecs < 0) {
    next_timeout_millisecs = 1; // remember, zero means wait forever
  }

  timeout.time_t = next_timeout_millisecs/1000;
  timeout.suseconds_t = (next_timeout_millisecs%1000)*1000;

  // Wait for events:
  retval = select(maxNumberOfIO, readableIOList, writableIOList, NULL, timeout);

  // Process event:
  if (retval == -1) {
    perror("Invalid select()");
  }
  else if (retval) {
    //  Find which file descriptor triggered the event
    for (i=0; i<maxNumberOfIO; i++) {
      if (FD_ISSET(i, readableIOList) && readable_task_queue[i]) {
        call_js_callback(readable_task_queue[i]);
      }
      if (FD_ISSET(i, writableIOList) && writable_task_queue[i]) {
        call_js_callback(writable_task_queue[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    // If we reach here it means we've timed out.
    // So call the timer callback:

    call_js_callback(nearest_timer);
  }
}
```

As you can see, because timers work differently from normal I/O events we use a separate timer event queue.

To get better familiarity with the logic flow you can try implementing a simple single-threaded server in C/C++ yourself using the `select()` system call. I've done it several times. The first time as a homework assignment in college and one time when I was tasked with adding asynchronous I/O to the [Ferite](https://ferite.sourceforge.net/#:%7E:text=ferite%20is%20a%20scripting%20engine,to%20get%20here%20so%20far.) programming language.

Comment: The term "task" in the html spec refers to a handler that is executed (or: becomes ready to execute) when an even occurs. Your answer however uses the meaning where a "task" is something ongoing that emits the events (like completion). This makes it a bit confusing.

Comment: Are you certain that JS runtimes do not continue polling the OS while executing the callbacks in parallel? Sure, it can be done on only a single thread in lockstep, without an actual queue, but using one (or multiple) queues seems like a natural extension for a multithreaded implementation.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure how you're reading the code but it's obvious that the thing that's ongoing is the OS itself and the thing that's waiting is the `select()` function. I'm using tasks to mean a data structure that stores the callback (eg. `task.callback` or `call_js_function(task)`) which is how it's defined in the spec.

Comment: As for how js runtimes implement the wait, it depends. In Node.js they use the OS async I/O feature (eg. `select()`) to wait for network events but they use a thread pool to manage disk event. It's not impossible to use async I/O programming for disk events (as is done in the Tcl programming language) but is kind of messy when it comes to doing it on Windows. Thus it's simpler to do traditional blocking I/O and then use IPC to asynchronously update the main thread.

Comment: @Bergi Basically Node.js uses pipes as the asynchronous primitive for managing disk I/O which internally they handle using blocking reads and writes in threads.